# Setting values in large tuples efficiently

Tags: python, tuples, ros, large-data

I am using ROS and I am currently trying to munipulate a costmap, so essentially I am wanting to change individual values in a tuple that has a length in this situation of approaching 7 digits.

See http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html

Originally I tried just turning this long tuple into a list then changing the values and then turning this back into a tuple, as you can imagine this extremely inefficient. I need this to be able to run quickly as it needs to update the costmap often for dynamic object avoidance.

Is there a way that I can change individual values in a tuple efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, this is simply a limitation of ROS's [python message data model](http://wiki.ros.org/msg). Array-like structures are always deserialized as `tuple` for performance reasons, except for lists of `bool` for some reason. And `tuple` is immutable.

However, if you were in C++ space, you would be receiving a `const OccupancyGridConstPtr&` anyway, so it would still be just as immutable. Or you could have registered the callback as `OccupancyGrid message` and get pass-by-value, but you're just moving the copy to method-call-time. There's no avoiding the copy if you intend on modifying the grid, wether you're in Python or C++.

There is no need to convert back to tuple however, ROS's python message serialization accepts either `list` or `tuple`.

You can gain quite a bit of efficiency as well if you can do some of your processing work during that copy (saves an iteration over the grid). Though I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, so I don't know the feasibility of that.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that tuples are immutable is supposed to be *a feature, not a bug*.
So if you need to make changes, the data probably ought not to be in tuple form in the first place.
Can't you have a list from begin to end? (I do not know ROS)

If that is impossible, I'd say you either have a serious problem with the software design or you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: No, you can't. ROS deserializes array-like members of messages as tuple in Python for performance reasons (and in C++ it would be a `const Vector&`, so roughly equivalent).